# Hide folder names, board names and the project settings page in Azure DevOps from users in a group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, pipeline

Is it possible to hide:

- board names in dropdowns in the Boards menu
- folder name is the Pipelines menu
- the Project settings page
  from users of a given user group in Azure DevOps?
  [Boards menu dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioP7Z.png)
  [Pipelines menu folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIsav.png)

I can hide the pipelines and work items but not the pipeline folders and board names in the dropdowns.

Answer (score 1):

I added one user in the **readers group** to access the Azure DevOps project, the user was able to view the boards and the Work items like below but was unable to edit it due to reader role :-

[image]

Now, I visited the ***Project Settings with my Admin Account > Boards > Team configuration > Areas > Security > View work items in this node > Deny***

[image]

[image]

***Now, When I route back to my user who's added to Readers group > The Work Items in Boards are not visible like below:-***

[image]

To Deny access to Pipelines, Refer the following setting below:-

**Go to Pipelines > three dots > Manage security> Deny > View Build pipeline and View builds like below:-**

[image]

[image]

***The Pipeline folder is not visible to the user like below:-***

[image]

References:-

[permissions - Azure DevOps deny access to Pipelines - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57907600/azure-devops-deny-access-to-pipelines) by Shamrai Aleksander

[How to restrict work item visibility/access to the team only in Azure DevOps | by Zaniar | Medium](https://medium.com/@zaniarr/how-to-restrict-work-item-visibility-access-to-the-team-only-in-azure-devops-b01643eee7ba) By zaniar